# Oracle SQL - Return value for each concatenated list ID in field

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with an Oracle 11g database.  I have a table of Items which includes a field representing the Item's associated products.  The data in the products field may or may not contain a list of concatenated values separated by commas, where each value corresponds to the product ID in an alternate lookup table which contains the product name.  If at least one product value is present in the products field, the field will start with and end with a comma.

```
ITEM TABLE
╔══════╦═══════════════════╗
║ ITEM ║ PRODUCTS          ║
╠══════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 12   ║ ,101,102,103,     ║
║ 34   ║ ,103,105,         ║
║ 56   ║ ,101,102,104,105, ║
║ 78   ║                   ║
║ 90   ║ ,102,             ║
╚══════╩═══════════════════╝

PRODUCTS TABLE
╔════════════╦══════╗
║ PRODUCT_ID ║ NAME ║
╠════════════╬══════╣
║ 101        ║ PA   ║
║ 102        ║ PB   ║
║ 103        ║ PC   ║
║ 104        ║ PD   ║
║ 105        ║ PE   ║
╚════════════╩══════╝
```

My goal is to do a SELECT query to get a list of Items with their concatenated product names by vertical bar but I'm not sure how to get there.

```
DESIRED RESULT
╔══════╦═════════════╗
║ ITEM ║ PRODUCTS    ║
╠══════╬═════════════╣
║ 12   ║ PA|PB|PC    ║
║ 34   ║ PC|PE       ║
║ 56   ║ PA|PB|PD|PE ║
║ 78   ║             ║
║ 90   ║ PB          ║
╚══════╩═════════════╝
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: That's a wrong DB design. You should never have comma separated values in table which is against normalization. Your table is not even in 1st normal form.

Comment: @apatto03 - Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Understand and agree; it's not from a database we designed nor control.

Comment: @GurV Oracle DB 11.2.0.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma separated values is not the right way to store data. Consider normalizing the schema.

What you can do is first convert the comma separated list into separate rows using hierarchical `connect by` and then join the result with products table and finally, use listagg to aggregate the product names back to `|` separated values.

```
select i.item,
    listagg(p.name, '|') within group (order by p.product_id) as products
from (
    select item,
        regexp_substr(trim(',' from products), '[^,]+', 1, level) as product_id
    from item connect by prior item = item
        and level <= regexp_count(trim(',' from products), ',') + 1
        and prior sys_guid() is not null
    ) i
left join products p on i.product_id = p.product_id
group by i.item;
```

Produces:

```
ITEM    PRODUCTS
-------------------
12      PA|PB|PC
34      PC|PE
56      PA|PB|PD|PE
78      
90      PB
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/HAYST99376)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split this comma separated string and gives the individual strings as rows. Using this:

```
select distinct ITEM_ID
        ,regexp_substr(PRODUCTS, '[^,]+', 1, level) PRODUCT_ID
    from item connect by regexp_substr(PRODUCTS, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
```

Using this query above as a table you can join with your main table.

```
select I.ITEM_ID
    ,P.PRODUCT_NAME
from ITEM I
inner join (
    select distinct ITEM_ID
        ,regexp_substr(PRODUCTS, '[^,]+', 1, level) PRODUCT_ID
    from item connect by regexp_substr(PRODUCTS, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
    ) X on X.ITEM_ID = I.ITEM_ID
inner join PRODUCTS P on P.PRODUCT_ID = X.PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: You connect by will not work correctly for more than one row.